# Google Apps Script で doPost の処理に時間がかかって doPost が再び呼ばれてしまうことに関して

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Script で doPost の処理に時間がかかっていると，doPost が再び（2分後に）呼ばれていたので，LockService の getUserLock や getScriptLock で再入防止を試みましたが，ロックを取得できてしまいます．他のタブやウィンドウから競合するようにPOSTすると，そちらではロックを取得できません．どこに問題があるでしょうか？

```
function doPost() {

  //var lock = LockService.getUserLock(); 
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); 
  var success = lock.tryLock(3);
  if (!success) { // 3秒以内にロックが取れなければ，前の処理が終わっていないと判断．
    console.error('doPost was called while processing doPost.');
    outHtml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile ("Wait a minute.");
    return outHtml.evaluate();
  }

  try {
    Utilities.sleep(180000);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

結局，userProperties からユーザのプロパティとして実行状態（処理中，受付中）を記録して，処理中に呼ばれても新たに処理を始めないようにしました．開始時間も記録して，一定時間経過していれば実行を受け付けるようにしました．